# How do I inspect mail messages in Behat tests?

Tags: 8, emails, testing

I am  writing a Behat Scenario that checks that an email generated by the Drupal system under test is sent to the correct recipient but I [could not] capture the mail messages from `test_mail_collector`. How do I do this?

**[Update]**
The code below is essentially my current working version and should work for you ... at least as long as you don't have an anti-spam module interceding ... in which case see the extra code in my answer.

In `FeatureContext.php` I switch over to the mail system sender `test_mail_collector` in the `@BeforeScenario` tagged with `@email` and revert to the site's original mail system sender in the `@AfterScenario` tagged with `@email`.

However, [before I discovered my answer, there were] never any messages in the array returned by `\Drupal::state()->get('system.test_mail_collector')` when a scenario should generate them,

Here's a typical scenario:

```
...
@email
Scenario: Send an email when a user resets her password
Given users:
  | name    | mail           | status |
  | Jo User | jo@example.com | 1      |
When I visit "user/password"
And I fill in "name" with "jo@example.com" 
When I press the "Submit" button
Then an email should be sent to "jo@example.com"
```

And here are the `FeatureContext.php` snippets:

```
...
/**
*  @Then an email should be sent to :recipient
*/
public function anEmailShouldBeSentTo($recipient)
{
  // Reset state cache.
  \Drupal::state()->resetCache();
  $mails = \Drupal::state()->get('system.test_mail_collector') ?: array();
  $last_mail = end($mails);
  if(!$last_mail) {
    throw new Exception('No mail was sent.');
  }
  if ($last_mail['to'] != $recipient) {
    throw new \Exception("Unexpected recpient: " . $last_mail['to']);
  }
  $this->lastMail = $last_mail;
}

/** 
 *  @BeforeScenario @email
 */
public function beforeEmailScenario(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
{
  $this->m_config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('mailsystem.settings');
  $this->saved_mailsystem_defaults = $this->m_config->get('defaults'); 
  $this->m_config->set('defaults.sender', 'test_mail_collector')->save();
  \Drupal::state()->set('system.test_mail_collector', array());
}

/** 
 *  @AfterScenario @email 
 */
public function afterEmailScenario(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
{
  // revert mail system after scenarios agged with @email
  $this->m_config->set('defaults.sender', $this->saved_mailsystem_defaults['sender'])->save();
}
```

The website is normally set up to run with `swiftmailer` enabled but I have tried all the other available mail system formatters and senders - like `Default PHP Mailer` - without success.

As a kind of "proof of setup" within `FeatureContext.php`, I can send test messages to the `test_mail_collector`:

```
$language_interface = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')
    ->mail('test', 'test', 'jo@example.com', $language_interface->getId());
```

This shows me that the `test_mail_collector` is working - but messages generated from the website [were] not being collected.

Comment: https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/issues/195 has code samples for a wide range of approaches to testing emails with Behat & Drupal.

Comment: https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/pull/392 is a PR to add this kind of functionality to the Drupal Behat extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you don't have anti-spam modules installed and doing their job!

The `@BeforeScenario` and `@AfterScenario` code in the original question is correct except in the case where you have an anti-spam module that is interfering with a `Scenario`.

For example, if  you've got `honeypot` installed, ensure that you disable the `time_limit` setting. `time_limit` is there to protect the Drupal site against spambots .... and test programs! ... on the assumption that humans can't enter stuff in less than a few seconds whereas bots and test programs do so almost instantaneously.

So, if you, as I did, have `honeypot` installed, then you will need to temporarily disable `time_limit` for the duration of the test. For example my `@BeforeScenario` and `@AfterScenario` code is now as follows:

```
/** 
   *  @BeforeScenario @email
   */
  public function beforeEmailScenario(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
  {
    $this->m_config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('mailsystem.settings');
    $this->saved_mailsystem_defaults = $this->m_config->get('defaults'); 
    $this->m_config
      ->set('defaults.sender', 'test_mail_collector')
      ->set('defaults.formatter', 'test_mail_collector')
      ->save();
    // Reset the state variable that holds sent messages.
    \Drupal::state()->set('system.test_mail_collector', array());

    // If we have honeypot installed then ensure that we disable time_limit
    // So that automated tests / bots can run  
    $this->h_config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('honeypot.settings');
    $this->saved_honeypot_time_limit = $this->h_config->get('time_limit');
    if ($this->saved_honeypot_time_limit) {
      $this->h_config
        ->set('time_limit', '0')
        ->save();
    }
  }

  /** 
   *  @AfterScenario @email 
   */
  public function afterEmailScenario(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
  {
    // revert mail system after scenarios agged with @email
    $this->m_config
      ->set('defaults.sender', $this->saved_mailsystem_defaults['sender'])
      ->set('defaults.formatter', $this->saved_mailsystem_defaults['formatter'])
      ->save();

    // Ensure we protect against spambots again if honeypot is installed
    if ($this->saved_honeypot_time_limit) {
      $this->h_config
        ->set('time_limit', $this->saved_honeypot_time_limit)
        ->save();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If an anti-spam module like honeypot is disabling a test because it detects that the form completion is too fast to be human, consider adding a delay to your test steps.

```
When I visit "user/password"
And I wait for 2 seconds
And I fill in "name" with "jo@example.com" 
And I wait for 1 second
When I press the "Submit" button
Then an email should be sent to "jo@example.com"
```

I suggest this gives a simpler and more realistic test than messing with the anti-spam settings. You'll need to add a step definition something like:

```
/**
 * @Given /^I wait ([0-9^"]*) seconds$/
 */
public function iWaitSeconds($wait) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < $wait; $i++) {
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

(Borrowed from http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/test-wrangling#.VqS6J_mLQYs, also see http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/cookbook/using_spin_functions.html)

Comment: Yes, the wait will be useful in other cases too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above configuration did not work for me properly as it failed to swap the mail handler plugin to the test one.
According to https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Tests%21Mail%21MailTest.php/8.2.x?no_cache=1475753055
the following worked for me

```
/**
   * Swaps the mailing system settings with a test one.
   *
   * @BeforeScenario @email
   */
  public function beforeEmailScenario() {
    $this->mailConfig = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.mail');
    $this->savedMailDefaults = $this->mailConfig->get('interface.default');
    $this->mailConfig->set('interface.default', 'test_mail_collector')->save();
    \Drupal::state()->set('system.test_mail_collector', array());
  }

  /**
   * Restores the mailing system settings with the default one.
   *
   * @AfterScenario @email
   */
  public function afterEmailScenario() {
    $this->mailConfig->set('interface.default', $this->savedMailDefaults)->save();
  }
```

These are only the before and after scenario. The rest are working fine.
Also, if you want to use the test plugin to work only for a specific case, you can use 'interface.mail_key' instead replacing the 'mail_key' with the mail key of your module.